# The best pattern for handling async looping in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm new to Node and trying to ensure that I'm using sane designs for a JSON-driven web app.

I've got a bunch of data stored in Redis and am retrieving it through node, streaming out the results as they come from Redis. Here's a good example of what I'm doing:

```
app.get("/facility", function(req, res) {
    rc.keys("FACILITY*", function(err, replies) {
        res.write("[");
        replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
            rc.get(reply, function(err, reply) {
                res.write(reply);
                if (i == replies.length-1) {
                    res.write("]");
                    res.end();
                }
                else
                    res.write(",");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Essentially I'm getting set of keys from Redis and then requesting each one, streaming out the result into semi-manually created JSON (the strings coming out of Redis are already in JSON). Now this works nicely, but I can't help thinking that the i == replies.length-1 is a little untidy?

I could do all this with mget in Redis, but that isn't really the point I'm trying to get it; it's how best to handle async looping with forEach, streaming the output and gracefully closing off the connection with res.end with the looping is done.

Is this the best way, or is there a more elegant pattern I could follow?

Comment: for deep nested function callbacks i would use the async.js library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above code might not do what you expect. You're kicking off each `.get()` in sequence, but they might not call back in sequence — so the results could stream out in any order. If you want to stream the results instead of collecting them in memory, you need to `.get()` in sequence.

I think that [caolan’s async library](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEach) makes a lot of this easier. Here’s one way you could use it to get each item in sequence (warning, untested):

```
app.get("/facility", function(req, res) {
    rc.keys("FACILITY*", function(err, replies) {
        var i = 0;
        res.write("[");
        async.forEachSeries(replies, function(reply, callback){
            rc.get(reply, function(err, reply) {
                if (err){
                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }
                res.write(reply);
                if (i < replies.length) {
                    res.write(",");
                }
                i++;
                callback();
            });
        }, function(err){
            if (err) {
                // Handle an error
            } else {
                res.end(']');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If you don’t care about the order, just use `async.forEach()` instead.

If you wouldn’t mind collecting the results and want them to return in sequence, you could use `async.map()` like this (warning, also untested):

```
app.get("/facility", function(req, res) {
    rc.keys("FACILITY*", function(err, replies) {
        async.map(replies, rc.get.bind(rc), function(err, replies){
            if (err) {
                // Handle an error
            } else {
                res.end('[' + replies.join(',') + ']');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's great; thanks for the code; I tried out the async library and it works perfectly. Order doesn't matter, but the map solution looks far more elegant, so I may just stick to that.

Comment: I'm trying to work out how the rc.get.bind(rc) parameter in the map function call works; it a nifty way of doing it. Could you explain a bit about how that works exactly?

Comment: @mjs [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is part of ECMAScript 5, and it returns a copy of a function which is “bound” to a particular `this` value. In this case, it means that when async.map calls the `get()`, it will have `rc` as its `this` value.

Comment: @mjs Normally, the value of `this` inside a function is determined by how you call it — calling a function *on* an object (like `rc.get()`) sets the value of `this` inside the function to `rc`. That’s determined at call time. If you were to do something like `var cb = rc.get; cb()` (which is the effect of passing it as an argument to `async.map`), it runs without the context of `rc`. Likewise, if you were to do `var foo = {}; foo.get = rc.get; foo.get();`, `get` would have `foo` as its context, not `rc`, and would probably behave very, very badly.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded explanation; appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry for answering on such and old post, but just wanted to let people know that if you are using hashes in redis, you will need to do a res.write(JSON.stringify(reply)); Thanks for the awesome answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, it provides some handy methods for looping, such as forEach:

> forEach(arr, iterator, callback)
>
> Applies an iterator function to each item in an array, in parallel.
>   The iterator is called with an item from the list and a callback for
>   when it has finished. If the iterator passes an error to this
>   callback, the main callback for the forEach function is immediately
>   called with the error.
>
> Note, that since this function applies the iterator to each item in
>   parallel there is no guarantee that the iterator functions will
>   complete in order.

**Example**

```
// assuming openFiles is an array of file names and saveFile is a function
// to save the modified contents of that file:

async.forEach(openFiles, saveFile, function(err){
    // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't help thinking that the i == replies.length-1 is a little untidy?

I've heard a lot of people say that. This is how I would do it by hand:

```
app.get("/facility", function(req, res, next) {
  rc.keys("FACILITY*", function(err, replies) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    var pending = replies.length;
    res.write("[");
    replies.forEach(function (reply) {
      rc.get(reply, function(err, reply) {
        res.write(reply);
        if (!--pending) {
          res.write("]");
          return res.end();
        }
        res.write(",");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Obviously doing it by hand isn't too pretty, which is why people have it abstracted into a library or some other function. But like it or not, that is how you do an async parallel loop. :)

You can use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library mentioned before to hide the nasty innards.