# How to write synchronous function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am newbie to Node.js and I am struggling with asynchronous calls.

In this below code I have an array of feeds for example(1,2,3..). each feed can contain multiple images and now  i want to delete the images from the folder and from database.

What i have done so far:

```
for(var i=0; i<feedArr.length; i++){
    var feedId = feedArr[i].feedid;
    var listFeedImageQuery  = "select imageUrl from feedImages where feedId='"+feedId+"'";
    var deleteFeedImagesQuery = "delete from feedImages where feedId='"+feedId+"'";
    model.client.query(listFeedImageQuery,function(err,result){
        if(result.rows.length > 0){
            for(var j=0; j<result.rows.length; j++){
                fs.unlink(result.rows[j].imageurl, function(err) {
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err);
                });
            }
            model.client.query(deleteFeedImagesQuery,function(err,result){
                if(err)
                    console.log(err)
                else
                    console.log(feedId +' were removed'); // last feedId only gets removing from database
            });
        }   
    });
}
```

Here I am able to delete the images from the image storage folder, but I am unable to delete the records from the database. Only the last feed record is getting deleted. The rest of the feedImage records are in database.

I researched something about async modules, but i don't know how to apply it to this issue.

Comment: You do know that it has a cyclical processing by one thread only don't you. Why on earth would you want to write synchronous function.

Comment: yes i know that, but in some situation its frustrating, do u know how to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best pattern for handling async looping in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579557/the-best-pattern-for-handling-async-looping-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

this is a common problem when switching to callback framework from the "standard" one.

This is how it works, first it synchronously run this

```
for(var i=0; i<feedArr.length; i++){
    var feedId = feedArr[i].feedid;
    var listFeedImageQuery  = "select imageUrl from feedImages where feedId='"+feedId+"'";
    var deleteFeedImagesQuery = "delete from feedImages where feedId='"+feedId+"'";
    model.client.query(listFeedImageQuery,function(err,result){
        //to be executed later
    });
}
```

The method `model.client.query` is pushed with each cycle to the "stack of asynchronous calls", therefore in the moment when the all these queries are executed, the feedId is equal to `feedArr[feedArr.length-1].feedid`

One simple workaround is to wrap it around methods with parameter and then call them immediately.

```
for(var i=0; i<feedArr.length; i++){        
    (function(feedId) {
       var listFeedImageQuery  = "select imageUrl from feedImages where feedId='"+feedId+"'";
       var deleteFeedImagesQuery = "delete from feedImages where feedId='"+feedId+"'";
       model.client.query(listFeedImageQuery,function(err,result){
           //to be executed later
       });
    })(feedArr[i].feedid);
}
```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log('sync', i);   
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('wrong async', i)
  }, 1);
}


for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
  setTimeout((function (j) {
    console.log('right async', i)
  })(i), 1);
}
```

[image]

Figure it out, maybe you will know where you was wrong.

---

For your issue, you can extract the async code as a function, like this:

```
function deleteImages(feedId) {
    var listFeedImageQuery  = "select imageUrl from feedImages where feedId='"+feedId+"'";
    var deleteFeedImagesQuery = "delete from feedImages where feedId='"+feedId+"'";
    model.client.query(listFeedImageQuery,function(err,result){
        if(result.rows.length > 0){
            for(var j=0; j<result.rows.length; j++){
                fs.unlink(result.rows[j].imageurl, function(err) {
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err);
                });
            }
            model.client.query(deleteFeedImagesQuery,function(err,result){
                if(err)
                    console.log(err)
                else
                    console.log(feedId +' were removed'); // last feedId only gets removing from database
            });
        }   
    });
}

for(var i=0; i<feedArr.length; i++){
    var feedId = feedArr[i].feedid;
    deleteImages(feedId);
}
```

---

For the more complex issue, if you don't want the callback hell, try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/)